# Why doesn't sIFR 3 wrap text around floating images?

Tags: css, text, css-float, sifr

Is sIFR supposed to wrap around floating images? I have some headings next to a large image float:left and the image bumps the headline down below it.

Headings that aren't beside floating images do wrap properly so the functionality is there, so my question is whether or not sIFR 3 text wraps beside floating images.

Answer (score 0):

The Flash movie being bumped below the image is something that can probably be worked around, but since a Flash movie is a rectangle, it'll never wrap *around* the image.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear: the goal isn't to get sIFR text to move around an image (in an odd shape) but to have it and an image float side by side. The Flash text can remain in a rectangle block, as long as the text flows properly.

Here's what I'm working on:

http://www.jeremyschultz.com/client/orchardplace/website/beta/pace/faq.html

The large image is float:left, but the sIFR subhead directly below it is bumped below it (rather than flow beside it). Maybe this is not possible?

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

I found that fitExactly will make the headings honor the floating graphics.

Comment: Whoops, now I've noticed that sIFR text that does NOT need to wrap will honor floating elements. But text that is long and does need multiple lines will not honor floating elements.  :(

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant originally.